# How can I attach a handrail to the wall so that it will be easily removable?

Tags: repair, handrail

I need a handrail on the wall of a narrow stairway that can be removed easily to transport furniture up or down the steps. Are there brackets that can be racheted off the wall instead of screws? Or 2 piece ones with flat base profile removing rail and sticking out part? Won't help  if brackets stick out after rail is removed. Don't want to unscrew from wall or wood compromising stability.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set up a removable stair railing?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15419/how-can-i-set-up-a-removable-stair-railing)

Comment: @NiallC. - I don't think it's a duplicate; the other question was regarding a staircase with one open side.  From the phrase "a narrow stairway", I'm guessing that this one is closed on both sides and needs a wall-mounted solution.  Pics would help, of course.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem by with t-nuts.  Embed the t-nuts into the stud, or in my case a wooden brace between the studs.  Then attach the bracket to the t-nut with a machine bolt.  I've screwed and unscrewed the bolt repeatedly but because it is metal-to-metal it does not compromise the wood and thus does not wobble.

(I agree this question is different than the one about a removable stair railing because this railing goes into the wall).

I haven't yet figured out how to mount such a wall rail into masonry.  A 2-part or removable bracket, as you ask, seems like a good idea but I haven't found one yet.